# Is whether a replication is continuous queryable anywhere?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-replication, merge-replication

Can I find whether a replication is continuous somewhere in the `distribution` or `msdb` databases on SQL Server database servers? (both 2005 and 2008)

Background:
I'm making a replication monitor system that will alert (by email) when a replication hasn't succesfully merged within X time. To do this, I'm periodically querying the `distribution` database's `MSreplication_monitordata` and `MSmerge_sessions` tables.
To test whether a replication has exceeded its alert time, I do the following for each entry in `MSreplication_monitordata` to see when the last succesful replication was:

```sql
select top 1 end_time
from MSmerge_sessions
where runstatus=2 and agent_id=@AgentId
order by end_time desc
```

runstatus=2 filters for "complete" status only ([see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173753%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

The problem is that continuous replications only have a single `MSmerge_sessions` entry that is continually having its end_time updated, but also has its state as 3, which means "in progress". I can't test for only that, since that would return non-continuous replication sessions which might fail before completing.

I tried seeing if the `MSmerge_sessions.current_phase_id` column might be useful, but it's undocumented and I can't infer what it means.
I've also tried the `msdb` database, since that's where the replication job records are being kept (in the `sysjobs` table). The `sysjobschedules` table seems promising, with some `next_run_date` and `next_run_time` fields being 0, but I can't find out how to link that to `sysjobs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so this is less pretty than I hoped for, but here it is:

```
select 
    agent.*,
    case when exists(
        select *
        from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps step
        where agent.job_id=step.job_id
        and step.step_id=2
        and step.command like '%-Continuous%')
        then 1
        else 0
    end as Continuous
from distribution.dbo.MSmerge_agents agent
```

Deduced from [this script](https://support.pelco.com/action.php?kt_path_info=ktcore.actions.document.view&fDocumentId=25837), which I found through desperate internet searches.
This assumes case-insensitivity for string matches.

If anyone has a better/neater/prettier solution, I'll still award the answer to them.